# Getting a landscape Tikz figure to fit on page

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-trees, landscape

I have the following large tree in tikz that I am trying to display as part of my thesis. Needless to say, the tree is to large to fit in portrait mode, so I have been trying to get it to fit in landscape mode but to no avail. I have tried fiddling with the node distances and level distances.... also to no avail. Could anyone help me and recommend the best way to present this tree so that it remains entirely visible?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, level 1/.style={sibling distance=300mm}, level 2/.style={sibling distance=150mm}, level 3/.style={sibling distance=75mm},  level 4/.style={sibling distance=40mm, level distance=35mm}]
\node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_5}$}
    child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_1}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_3}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
    }
    child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_1}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_3}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A Decision Tree}
\label{datfvo}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can recover a lot of width by varying the `level distance` (provided it doesn't offend your sense of symmetry).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, level 1/.style={sibling distance=180mm}, level 2/.style={sibling distance=90mm}, level 3/.style={sibling distance=45mm},  level 4/.style={sibling distance=20mm, level distance=25mm}]
\node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_5}$}
    child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_1}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_3}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
    }
    child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_1}$}
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_2} \gets 1$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
        child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_3}$}
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_2}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_1} \gets 0$}} 
            }
            child{node[circle, draw]{$b\smash{_4}$}
                child{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_4} \gets 1$}}
                child[level distance=40mm]{node[rectangle, draw]{$b\smash{_3} \gets 0$}} 
            }   
        }
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A Decision Tree}
\label{datfvo}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I've also used `pdflscape` to rotate the page in the resulting pdf.

[image: decision tree that fits]

Comment: That's really slick! I like it :)

Answer (score 3):

You could scale the individual nodes as well.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3, every node/.style={scale=0.7}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the geometry of the page to make sure there is no header//footer.

And you could also change your scaling, seems fine at 0.4 ?

If it's to small for you, then just implement `xscale=0.4` instead of the whole `scale=.5`

Comment: I can't manipulate the header and footer.... these are part of the formatting requirements of my thesis. I will try your other suggestion though.